# REST API for Trac.Wiki

Tags: wiki, api, trac

I wonder is there any kind of REST API for managing trac/wiki?
Googling helps to find something either quite updated or too raw (or both).
Searching this Stack, as well as [friendly ones](https://serverfault.com/questions/262112/way-to-export-import-trac-wiki-pages), also hasn't been much source of inspiration.

Correct me if I'm wrong (and forgive me my ignorance), but `trac-admin` can work only with repo hosted on the same machine, or mounted, whatever, but not with remote server.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [XmlRpcPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin) which supports JSON as well as XML format.  It's modelled as an RPC interface, rather than REST but it's easy to request things like a list of all tickets assigned to a user.